Wal-G an indexes
I'm migrating a PostgreSQL 15 database using wal-g.
After migration, everything seems to work as expected except for a unique constraint that's not being honored until I rebuild the index.
The constraint is unique, composite (varchar, int) and it specifies NULLS NOT DISTINCT.
OS are different, but collation is the same. Queries to text/bigint index seems to work.
My understanding was that wal-g performed "physical replication" so I shouldn't be having this issue.
What could it be wrong?

pretty sure https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes
